# How transistor convert DC to AC?

Tags: transistors

I'm fairly new to electricity. I know that a transistor can be used to convert DC to AC, but i really don't know why. Can anyone please explain how transistor can convert DC to AC ?

Comment: Where did you read/who told you that? A transistor by itself cannot convert DC to AC. It has to be part of a much larger system.

Comment: @MattYoung I asked a question here , and they mean the transistor in this circuit is using to convert DC to AC :( http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/112104/mosquito-racket-circuit?noredirect=1#comment224259_112104

Comment: I think the more appropriate question for you to ask is, "How can DC be sent through a transformer?" And the answer is that there are many ways. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched_mode_power_supply#Isolated_topologies

Comment: Sorry for my somewhat misleading answer, but you seemed to know enough about what you were talking about to put those things together and figure it out for yourself. Unfortunately you've gotten tangled up in terminology instead of concepts :/

Answer (score 1):

From context, I think what you're trying to ask is, "How can DC be sent through a transformer?" And the answer is that there are many ways. A few can be found here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_converter

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93pull_converter

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-Bridge

In general, they all involve using one or more transistors, which switch at high frequency (usually kHz or more) to change the direction of current flow through the transformer primary. The transformer doesn't really care whether it's got a perfect sine wave on it. You can send a triangle wave, a square wave, anything that changes direction through a transformer just fine. The transistors switch the direction of the current. Thus, "[Switched mode power supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched_mode_power_supply#Isolated_topologies)".

([Flyback converters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter) work a little differently, in that the current never actually reverses direction on the primary. Instead, you switch the current in the primary on and off, and the reverse current actually shows up on the secondary. A bit more complex, but pretty fascinating.)

Comment: As i learn in theory, the transformer can work only with AC. So theory is wrong ? In this case the current is still DC, it's just have frequency

Comment: I think your understanding of theory is wrong. Theory requires that the current through the transformer reverse direction periodically, and that the total flux built up in one half-cycle be canceled by the flux in the other half-cycle. The shape of the wave is of no consequence.

If you put a square wave (for example) through a transformer, it's not "DC with a frequency". DC, by definition, has no frequency.